# Iterating through (JSON?) map in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a datastructure like that:

```
sample_map= {'key1': {'internal_key1': ['value1']},
             'key2': {'internal_key2': ['value2']},
                 }
```

I would like to iterate throgh on every line key1 and key2. I would like to get the value of 'internal_key1' and 'value_1'variables.

I tried this way:

```
for keys in sample_map.keys():
    for value in sample_map[keys]:
        #get internal_keys and values
```

How should I do this? Someone maybe could tell me about this data structure and the using?

Comment: you may want to look at [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/). It will be very helpful for such kind of tasks on json files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
for k,v in sample_map.iteritems():
    print k
    for k1,v1 in v.iteritems():
        print k1,v1[0]
```

This will print the following:

```
key2
internal_key2 value2
key1
internal_key1 value1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for item in sample_map.values():
   for k, v in item.items():
      print k, v
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called a dictionary (type [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict)). It does resemble the JSON structure, although JSON is a format in which a string is built to represent a specific structure of data, and `dict` is a structure of data (that can be converted to a string in JSON format).

Anyway, this line - `for value in sample_map[keys]:` is invalid. To get the value linked to a key, you just have to do `value = sample_map[keys]`. In this example, `dict`s will be assigned to val. Those will be the inner `dict`s (`{'internal_key1': ['value1']}` and so on).

So to access the inner keys, call `.keys()` of `value`:

```
for keys in sample_map.keys():
    value = sample_map[keys]:
    for internal_key in value.keys():
        internal_value = value[internal_key]
```

Also, when using a for loop, there's no need for `dict.keys()`, it will be used automatically, so your code could look like:

```
for keys in sample_map:
    value = sample_map[keys]:
    for internal_key in value:
        internal_value = value[internal_key]
```